# Difference between 3.0.x and 3.11.x versions of cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm currently using Cassandra version of 3.0.14 on my RHEL cluster. I've found that multiple versions have been released after the version that I'm currently using(http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/). I'm confused about how should I upgrade my cluster because both 3.0.x and 3.11.x had their last version released on 19th Feb, 2018. So what exactly are the differences between the latest release of 3.0.x and latest release of 3.11.x. if 3.11.x is superior, then, should I directly upgrade my cluster from 3.0.14 to 3.11.2? Will all my data remain safe even after the upgrade?

Comment: First I would suggest you to read the release notes https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.2 and changes https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.2

Comment: By changing the cassandra version on the previous links you could see the release notes and changes for other versions.

Comment: the current stable release is 3.0.16, so you'll be moving from "stable" to "latest" if or when you migrate to 3.11.2.

Comment: @LHWizard how do you say if a release is stable? Both 3.0.16 and 3.11.2 were modified on the same date i.e. 19-2-2018(http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/)

Comment: @Horia, in the second link that you've provided, when I compare the list of bug fixes of, say, 3.11.2 with 3.11.1, I see that both have 'merged from 3.0' section. What does that mean? And also, both have got different number of bug fixes merged from 3.0? Can you help me in making sense of this?

Comment: @VishalSharma As you know, currently there are 4 Cassandra supported versions: 2.1, 2.2, 3.0 and 3.x. When there is something solved on older versions, like 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, if applicable, it's also solved on 3.x, that's why you see those "Merged from...".

Comment: @VishalSharma are you ok with the provided info? Is it ok to put it as answer?

Comment: @Horia I'm still not able to figure out on which version is it appropriate to upgrade my cluster which is currently on 3.0.14. To me it seems that since 3.11.2 is the latest, therefore, it will be the one having the most features and least bugs. However, I see that 3.0.16 was also released at the same time. This is what is confusing me. I also don't know the procedure of upgrading the cluster.

Comment: @VishalSharma This discussion might help to decide which version you should go for https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201801.mbox/%3cCAM3v5Fs1W93UUiwfY=fzMFqk-abVGgOXsZxS_y6oQew2kPXuWw@mail.gmail.com%3e

Comment: @VishalSharma also this discussion might help https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201803.mbox/%3c000001d3b277$05909490$10b1bdb0$@yahoo.com%3e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the versions: you should check for [changes](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.2) and [release notes](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.2) for each version.

Also, these discussions might help in order to take a good decision regarding what version to upgrade to: [1](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201801.mbox/%3CCAM3v5Fs1W93UUiwfY=fzMFqk-abVGgOXsZxS_y6oQew2kPXuWw@mail.gmail.com%3E), [2](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201803.mbox/%3C000001d3b277$05909490$10b1bdb0$@yahoo.com%3E).

As upgrade procedure, see below a guideline.

- backup the cluster (data, binaries, config)
- check upgrade info in news
- upgradesstables (before upgrade all sstables must have the same version)
- drain
- stop node
- backup config
- update binaries
- update config
- start
- check logs/status.
  After the whole cluster is upgrade, run upgradesstables on each node.

Some observations:

- perform a rolling upgrade, each node at a time
- do not do schema changes, repairs, topology changes, streaming (as in bootstrap)
- after you run upgradesstables, check that all sstables files are at the same version; if necessary, rerun upgradesstables.
- upgrade seed nodes first within a DC
- finish a DC and go to next
- watch out for page state if you upgrade from 2.2 to 3.0 - you cannot run paged queries, check [JIRA 10880](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10880) (I know it's not your case but others might find it useful).
- test the upgrade several times on some test environment before doing it on a production cluster.

Also, these articles might provide useful information on the upgrade: [1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdCstarToDSE.html), [2](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE50.html)